# Extract a dll from a nuget package using nuget.client

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to extract a dll from a nuget package programatically and load the dll at runtime.

I want to avoid using any command line tools - I want my program to be completely self contained, and not rely on external executables.

I am trying to use the various nuget.client nuget packages listed at https://www.nuget.org/profiles/nuget, but there is no documentation for them whatsoever and I can't work out how.

I have the nupkg, and I am able to work out the location of the dll in the nupkg via a PackageReader, but I don't know how to extract the nupkg so that I can get the file out.

Edit

Thanks to the people who have pointed out that a nupkg is just a zip. I've now done the following:

```cs
            var archive = new ZipArchive(downloadResourceResult.PackageStream);

            var entry = archive.GetEntry(dllPath);

            var assemblyLoadContext = new System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext(null, isCollectible: true);
            var assembly = assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(entry.Open());
```

However this throws a NotSupportedException with the following stack trace

```
System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.get_Length()   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(Stream assembly, Stream assemblySymbols)   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(Stream assembly)
```

Comment: A tip : Its a zip file

Comment: nupkg files are just zip files.  Simply unzip as normal, and look in the appropriate subfolder...

Comment: Ok I've done that. Now when I try to load it from the zip file stream I get a NotSupportedException from System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.get_Length()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a full method to download a nuget package and load it. It's just a POC - you'll want to configure it for your use case.

```cs
        public async Task<Assembly> LoadFromNuget(string id, string version, string? nugetFeedUrl = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var repository = Repository.Factory.GetCoreV3(nugetFeedUrl ?? "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
            var downloadResource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<DownloadResource>();
            if (!NuGetVersion.TryParse(version, out var nuGetVersion))
            {
                throw new Exception($"invalid version {version} for nuget package {id}");
            }
            using var downloadResourceResult = await downloadResource.GetDownloadResourceResultAsync(
                new PackageIdentity(id, nuGetVersion),
                new PackageDownloadContext(new SourceCacheContext()),
                globalPackagesFolder: Path.GetTempDirectory(),
                logger: _nugetLogger,
                token: cancellationToken);

            if (downloadResourceResult.Status != DownloadResourceResultStatus.Available)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Download of NuGet package failed. DownloadResult Status: {downloadResourceResult.Status}");
            }

            var reader = downloadResourceResult.PackageReader;

            var archive = new ZipArchive(downloadResourceResult.PackageStream);

            var lib = reader.GetLibItems().First()?.Items.First();

            var entry = archive.GetEntry(lib);

            using var decompressed = new MemoryStream();
            entry.Open().CopyTo(decompressed);

            var assemblyLoadContext = new System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext(null, isCollectible: true);
            decompressed.Position = 0;
            return assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(decompressed);
        }
```

You'll have to implement or use a version of the Nuget ILogger to download the nupkg.

Answer (score 7):

1. You can rename the nuget extension to zip extension and should be able to extract to folder.
   [image: Renaming Nuget extension to zip extension]
2. Now, you can get the dlls from the extracted folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution will get you dll and neGetproj file

```
public static void InstallDlls()
{
   //ID of the package to be looked 
    string package = "EntityFramework";

    //Connect to the official package repository IPackageRepository
    IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://nuget.testsys.com/nuget");

    string path = @"YourTargetPath";
    //Initialize the package manager string path = <PATH_TO_WHERE_THE_PACKAGES_SHOULD_BE_INSTALLED>
    PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, path);

    //Download and unzip the package 
    packageManager.InstallPackage(package, NuGet.SemanticVersion.Parse("5.0.0"));
}
```